# MVC - Expandable Partial View within ForEach loop

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, expandable

I have a View with a model of type:

```
IEnumerable<StoreMonthlyTarget>
```

Here is the class

```
public partial class StoreMonthlyTarget
{
    public int STORE_KEY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> RetailYear { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> RetailMonthID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<F_MonthlyTargets> EmployeeTargets { get; set; }
}
```

In my Index view, I loop over each `StoreMonthlyTarget`. I then want to be able to click on any of these, and expand a *PartialView* that will show the attached list of `F_MonthlyTargets`.

So far, I have this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Store</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>
                Expand
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Store)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RetailMonth)</td>
            <td>
            <input type="button" value="Expand" id="btnExpand"
            onclick="javascript:BtnOnclick('@item.STORE_KEY'
                                          ,'@item.RetailYear'
                                          ,'@item.RetailMonthID');"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="divpopup" style="display:none">
        @Html.Partial("_Store", item);
    </div>
```

This passes the keys needed into a function

```
<script>
function BtnOnclick(Store, Year, Month) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Targets/PartialStore")',
        data: {
            store: Store,
            year: Year,
            month: Month
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#divpopup').css("display", "block");
            $('#btnExpand').css("display", "none");
            $('#divpopup')[0].innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
}
function CollapseDiv() {
    $('#divpopup').css("display", "none");
    $('#btnExpand').css("display", "block");
}
</script>
```

That in turn, uses those keys to find the record needed and return it.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialStore(string store
                                , string year
                                , string month)
{
    StoreMonthlyTarget s =  (
                             from a in db.StoreMonthlyTargets
                             where a.RetailMonthID.ToString() == month
                                && a.RetailYear.ToString() == year
                                && a.STORE_KEY.ToString() == store
                             select a
                            ).ToList()[0];
    s.EmployeeTargets = (
                         from t in db.F_MonthlyTargets
                         where t.STORE_KEY == s.STORE_KEY
                            && t.RetailYearID == s.RetailYear
                            && t.RetailMonthID == s.RetailMonthID
                                select t
                         );
        return PartialView("_Store", s);
    }
```

The Partial view is then of type `StoreMonthlyTarget`, and contains a table that loops over the `EmployeeTargets` in here.

When I run it, i get my list of Stores. I then click on the button, and it retrieves the correct store. But every time it places the *PartialView* `div` after the first Store item. Not under the corresponding entry.

Anyone have any ideas as to why? Perhaps it's badly structured and there are better ways to do this?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: `<div id="divpopup">` is repeated by your for loop. Duplicate ids are not valid. Your success handler is using the first instance of the id it finds.